# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Favorite'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Favorite'`

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Share'`

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'`

This issue started after i upgraded to React version 18. I have followed all the instructions given online but it still doesn't work.

I have installed this
`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps npm install @mui/icons-material --legacy-peer-deps`

Yet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The path that you're importing the icons from is wrong, it seems like in the newer version of Material UI, you import icons from `@mui/icons-material` and not from `@material-ui/icons/`. It's listing [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#main-content) in the MUI's page